# Get the RFID text without QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have an QLineEdit that will take the value of an RFID tag and the log the user in with the value that is received, I have setup the QLineEdit so that it calls a login function when the enter key is pressed.

The only issue that I am left with is that the QLineEdit is visible which is not necessary as the user will not be typing the value of their RFID tag, they will just scan it and the scanner will enter the value and press enter.

```
rfid_enter = QLineEdit()
rfid_enter.returnPressed.connect(lambda: log_user_in(rfid_enter.text()))


def log_user_in(value):
    print(value) (THIS WILL LOG THE USER IN)
```

Comment: Do you want to detect the RFID text without using a QLineEdit ?, if so, then be direct in your question, something like: "Get the RFID text without QLineEdit"

Comment: Apologies, have done so.

Comment: In your window what other widget do you have?

Comment: two labels, and a few spacers.

Answer (score 1):

QLineEdit needs to have the focus to get the keyboard events, but to have the focus it needs to be visible, so hiding it will not be the solution.

As pointed out by the OP in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821496/get-the-rfid-text-without-qlineedit#comment100196091_56821496) in the window there are only: *two labels, and a few spacers* that do not handle the keyboard event so there are no widgets that intercept that event so the window can get them without problems (if there are other widget like QLineEdits, QTextEdit, QSpinBox, etc. the logic could change).

Considering the above, I have implemented the following logic:

```
import string
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    returnPressed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(
            QtWidgets.QLabel("My Label", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter),
            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop,
        )
        self.m_text = ""
        self.returnPressed.connect(self.log_user_in)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.text() in string.ascii_letters + string.digits:
            self.m_text += event.text()
        if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter):
            self.returnPressed.emit(self.m_text)
            # clear text
            self.m_text = ""
        super(Widget, self).keyPressEvent(event)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def log_user_in(self, text):
        print(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(240, 320)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, I dont want the QLineEdit to ever be visible as the user does not need to see the box that they are entering the RFID value into, they will simply scan the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from eyllanesc would work if the entire window was the class that he had created, but in my case the layout will change and therefore I could not use that as the main window.

I went for a cheat approach of just trying to hide the box as much as possible and ended up with this result.

```
class LogInRFIDListener(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LogInRFIDListener, self).__init__()
        self.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextEditable)
        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.setStyleSheet("border: none; color: transparent;")  # Hide the border around the text box
        self.setCursorWidth(0)  # Hide the cursor

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):  # Major restricting needed
        if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter):
            log_user_in(self.toPlainText())
        super(LogInRFIDListener, self).keyPressEvent(event)
```